# Image button or button with a background image in XCode, what is better?

Tags: ios, xcode, imagebutton

I am quite new in XCODE and I am making an app. In the main menu of the app I would like to put a series of buttons one after another. Each button will have each own image. My question is: should I have an Image Button for each button or should I have buttons with the corresponding images as backgrounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIButton with image as background are better (especially if your images are set in an xcassets because in that case you can even defined slicing methods : how the image should react if the button size changes for example).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick reply!

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use a button with an image on the background, because the main functionality for that is a UIButton library. You don't need to setup the tapgesture or any other functionality. you get all the button behavior since the function of that image will be a button and not a regular image.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick reply!